# Sourcing from a different bashrc

Tags: linux, bash

My original .bashrc script is currently used to run model runs. Now I need to manipulate it to compile a completely new model.

My question is, if I save my original .bashrc, as something such as .bwwbashrc, do I need to manipulate the file in some way so it is able to be read or recognized as the .bashrc when I source it within my scripts?

original sourcing

```
source /home/tsee/.bashrc
```

What I think the new sourcing would be.
(after creating .bwwbashrc)

```
source /home/tsee/.bwwbashrc
```

Just not sure if I need to save it with a certain extension or edit the executable in some sort of way.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you can name it whatever you want. Executable bit isn't required either.

If you aren't aware of it, the bash `--login` option might be of interest to you.

Comment: I imagine just as long as I don't forget the "." before it? Or does that just hide the file?

Comment: @twseewx you can source whatever you want, the filename is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @twseewx *"Or does that just hide the file?** You got it.

Answer (score 1):

To complement Matt’s correct answer, I’d also point out that you can start a *new* Bash shell that sources your alternative file *instead of* `.bashrc` at start-up.

```
bash --rcfile .bwwbashrc
```

From the bash man page:

> `--rcfile file`
>
> Execute commands from file instead of the standard personal initialization
>   file ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive (see INVOCATION below).

If you want to *replace* your current shell (with commands and settings from `.bashrc`), you can run

```
exec bash --rcfile .bwwbashrc
```